# Get information on Usb Zwave key in Java

Tags: java, usb, driver, z-wave

I would like to get informations about a Zwave usb key in java, to access to its functions because I would like to write a program who can handle different connected devices using Zwave network.

Someone have an idea to get access to this informations and functions in Java ?

(Sorry if there are some misunderstanding in my sentences, I'm not English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 frameworks to access USB devices in Java. Both wrap native libraries. One is specifically for HID devices (not sure of this applies to ZWave). I dont know if they have all the features required to speak to your zWave devices, but they would be the first thing to try.

- http://www.usb4java.org
- https://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/

Both implement the JSR-80 javax.usb API (which might be too high level).

Comment: It seems I will be able to do it with usb4java ! Thanks